# How to replace numbers in an XML file with their double value?

Tags: text-processing

Input file "input.xml":

```
<integer name="leftValue">30</integer>
<integer name="rightValue">580</integer>
<integer name="rightValueDefault">495</integer>
```

I want every numeric value multiplied by 2:

```
<integer name="leftValue">60</integer>
<integer name="rightValue">1160</integer>
<integer name="rightValueDefault">990</integer>
```

How to do that?

Comment: use a xml parser

Comment: People, stop voting to close text parsing questions as off topic! They aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [you shouldn't parse HTML / XML using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2461638).

However, if your input file is really like the one shown in the example (a single opening and closing tag on each line and no `>` character before the end of the opening tag), using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/>([0-9]+)/">".$1*2/e' in
```

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `>`: matches a `>` character
- `([0-9]+)`: matches and groups one or more digits
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `">".$1*2`: expression; concatenation of two strings, a `>` character and the first captured group multiplied by `2`
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the pattern flags
- `e`: asserts to evaluate the replacement string

```
% cat in
<integer name="leftValue">30</integer>
<integer name="rightValue">580</integer>
<integer name="rightValueDefault">495</integer>
% perl -pe 's/>([0-9]+)/">".$1*2/e' in
<integer name="leftValue">60</integer>
<integer name="rightValue">1160</integer>
<integer name="rightValueDefault">990</integer>
```

Comment: This is perfect, can't we achieve same with `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: @snoop `sed` has an option to evaluate expressions in the replacement string, but I'm unable to get it to work, despite lots of people seemingly using it. With `awk`yes, but again, this is *very* specific to your input: `awk '{x=$0; gsub(/<[^>]*>/, ""); gsub(/>[0-9]+/, ">"$0*2,x); print x}' in`

Comment: @snoop: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: [**Eek!**](//stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2461638) Down-voted for recommending regular expressions to parse XML. ;-P

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for commenting and for having explained the downvote, but I didn't recommend to use regexes to parse XML. I just provided a way to parse the exact file in the sample input, as I outlined in the first statement. That is true in general for complex HTML/XML, but not for the file in question, unless I'm not seeing where it could break.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/4316166 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/4316166 ;)

Comment: @kos: I agree, that on simple, well-behaving XML data, regular expressions can be the most simple tool. The difficulty is to know to distinct between these cases and those, that potentially encompass “strange” data. I generally tend to assume, that people, who need to ask this kind of question, do not possess that knowledge. So, my disagreement is for pedagogic reasons.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I agree on that also, and I respect your downvote in that point of view. But after OP's comments and acceptance I'm prone to think the input file, in the end, was exactly like that. However I added the link in your comment and a brief warning to not mislead future visitors, as I find "not parsing regular expressions" *in general* quite reasonable as well.

Comment: @kos: I tried this `sed -i 's/\(<[a-zA-Z0-9=" ]*>\)\([0-9]*\)\(<\/[a-zA-Z0-0 ]*>\)/echo "\1$((\2*2))\3"/e' in` just unable to maintain double quotes `"` in result.

Comment: @snoop This seems a little better, it won't break on empy matches on the second capturing group: `sed 's/^\([^>]*>\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)\(.*\)/echo "\1$((\2*2))\3"/e' in` However I can't get to insert double quotes neither. That's `sh` syntax, so I don't really know. Escaping doesn't seem to help. However is there a reason to not use Perl? I'll see if a figure out this double-quotes thing

Answer (score 3):

Use a proper XML parser. For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can just write

```
open input.xml ;
for //text if (. > 0) set . (2 * .) ;
save :b ;
```